# c++ rgb to hsv conversion

Tags: c++, colors, rgb, hsv

i am trying to write a program that converts `RGB` color space to `HSV` space. it is based on the conversion [algorithm described here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HSL_and_HSV) . most of the places i searched for has a similar algorithm for conversion.

```
my input to the program: 67 42 96
output: 267.778 , 0.5625, 96
                          ^^^^^ // it should be 38 as below
expected output: 268 56% 38%
                          ^^^^^^
```

i can see for other inputs also `H` & `S` values are as they should be but the `V` value is different. what could be the reason fot that?

```
#include<iostream>
#include <algorithm>    // std::max

using namespace std;


 void rgb2hsv(float r, float g, float b) {

     float h = 0.0;
     float s = 0.0;
     float v = 0.0;

     float min = std::min( std::min(r, g), b );
     float max = std::max( std::max(r, g), b );
     v = max;               // v

     float delta = max - min;

     if( max != 0.0 )
         s = delta / max;       // s
     else {
         // r = g = b = 0       // s = 0, v is undefined
         s = 0.0;
         h = -1.0;
         cout<<h<<" , "<<s<<" , "<<v<<endl;
     }
     if( r == max )
         h = ( g - b ) / delta;     // between yellow & magenta
     else if( g == max )
         h = 2.0 + ( b - r ) / delta;   // between cyan & yellow
     else
         h = 4.0 + ( r - g ) / delta;   // between magenta & cyan

     h = h * 60.0;              // degrees

     if( h < 0.0 )
         h += 360.0;

     cout<<h<<" , "<<s<<" , "<<v<<endl;
 }


int main(){
while(1){
float r,g,b;

cin>>r>>g>>b;

rgb2hsv(r,g,b);
}

return 0;
}
```

Comment: After checking with my own RGV->HSV conversion code, value is indeed the maximum value of all three color channels. Since the maximum value in your example is 96, that's the correct, and expected `v`. Perhaps you need to re-examine your expectations of some other value.

Comment: @SamVarshavchik but when i use color picker of google and select an rgb value it has different hsv value from my implementation. can you just check it once here https://www.google.co.in/search?q=color+picker&oq=color+picker&aqs=chrome.0.69i59j0l5.4164j0j1&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8

Comment: I have no knowledge of the internals of Google's color picker, so I can't make any comment on that. I can only state on what the definition of `v` is, as far as the general rgb-to-hsv conversion algorithm goes. There are many different variations of rgv->hsv conversion code. Some express the color channels as `float` or `double` values between 0-1. Other express the color channels as 8 or 16 bit integer values. You cannot compare the expected results of some arbitrary color picker versus your own unless yours uses the same exact representations of color channels as the other.

Comment: @SamVarshavchik oh ok , i think i am getting the point but still have some doubts as today is the first time i was reading about color spaces and color theory. will have to read some more i guess

Comment: 96 is indeed, 37.5% of 256. Google, indeed, chooses to represent values differently than your code, representing the value as a percentage of an 8-bit value. This wasn't so difficult to figure out, wasn't it? This is simple math.

Comment: what is 256 here?